# JavaScript Objection relation mapping

Tags: join, relation, objection.js

I am wondering if there is a way to solve my problem.
I want implement this type of join SQL `JOIN Records ON Accounts.id = Records.account_id OR Accounts.id = Records.from_account_id;` with Objection Relation Mapping, but it doesn't work for me,
need someting like that:

```
records: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: RecordModel,
        join: {
          from: getJoinRelationPath<AccountModel>(DatabaseTableName.ACCOUNTS, 'id'),
          to: 'records.accountId OR records.fromAccountId',
        }
      },




 records: {
          relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
          modelClass: Record,
          join: {
            from: 'accounts.id',
            to: 'records.account_id'
          }
        },
        recordsFrom: {
          relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
          modelClass: Record,
          join: {
            from: 'accounts.id',
            to: 'records.from_account_id'
          }
        }
      }
```

Found only this solution, but don't want to have separated fields

Comment: Using an `OR` in a `JOIN` predicate is not necessarily a good idea. Have you considered using two separate `LEFT OUTER JOIN` operators instead? and then using `COALESCE()` within the query, if necessary?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I guess I can rewrite it using it. Although wondering how I can represent it within Objection relation mapping.